# Registration Form twig add to an usergroup

Tags: form, registration

I just started using Craft and I'm a little stuck with a public registration form.
I made a user group and wanted to add these to the saveUser form.

I found  [this answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1774/how-do-you-set-a-users-group-on-a-registration-form)

but don't know where to find this code.

I'm working in a twig file. Do i have to make my own plugin for that? Or do I have to overwrite something?

```
<form method="post" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="users/saveUser">
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="/">
    <input type="hidden" name="userGroups" = "1">

    {% macro errorList(errors) %}
        {% if errors %}
            <ul class="errors">
                {% for error in errors %}
                    <li>{{ error }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
    {% endmacro %}

    {% from _self import errorList %}

    <h3><label for="username">Username</label></h3>
    <input id="username" type="text" name="username"
        {%- if account is defined %} value="{{ account.username }}"{% endif -%}>

    {% if account is defined %}
        {{ errorList(account.getErrors('username')) }}
    {% endif %}

    <h3><label for="email">Email</label></h3>
    <input id="email" type="text" name="email"
        {%- if account is defined %} value="{{ account.email }}"{% endif %}>

    {% if account is defined %}
        {{ errorList(account.getErrors('email')) }}
    {% endif %}

    <h3><label for="password">Password</label></h3>
    <input id="password" type="password" name="password">

    {% if account is defined %}
        {{ errorList(account.getErrors('password')) }}
    {% endif %}

    <input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

I tried adding a userGroups hidden input but that didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You can set the default user group through your admin:

[image]

2) Also I'm pretty sure `<input type="hidden" name="userGroups" = "1">` needs to be set to `<input type="hidden" name="userGroups" value="1">` for it to work but I'd need to test to be sure.

Comment: Thx, I did point 1 and it worked. Point 2 didn't worked after I corrected my attributes... maybe it should be another name.